# Completely removing toolbar and cell titles Excel

Tags: vba, excel, toolbar

I've designed a tool using many activex controls which is now completely working. Just to finish it off and make it look a bit cleaner I want to be able to completely remove the toolbar and column and row titles. Here is what my Sub Auto_Open() looks like:

```
Sub Auto_Open()

Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not Application.DisplayStatusBar
ActiveWindow.DisplayWorkbookTabs = True

On Error Resume Next
Sheets("UserInput").Activate
Range("A1").Select
With Application
    .WindowState = xlNormal
    .Left = 300
    .Top = 50
    .Width = 800
    .Height = 670
    .CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Enabled = False
    .CommandBars("Ribbon").Visible = False
End With

End Sub
```

Here is a screenshot of what this looks like:

[image]

I basically just want rid of everything that's not on the sheet, or if not just as much as possible. Anyone know of any way of doing this please? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
application.DisplayFullScreen = True
activewindow.DisplayHeadings = False
```

FYI, activex controls on worksheets are notoriously flaky. Form controls would be a better bet if you must put controls on a sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I've somehow managed to lock all the cells now. Any idea if any of these commands will do that? The sheet is still unprotected but there is one cell that I want the users to be able to edit.

Comment: Just unmark the "protect cell" check box under "protection" tab in window "format cell". Crtl + 1 should open it, at least it does in my Portuguese language pack.

Comment: @JamesBaker If the sheet is unprotected the users should be able to change anything they like.

Comment: @Rory Turns out it's nothing to do with protection. On the input page the user enters a value in a cell and then clicks 'sumbit' which takes them to an output page. I have a 'back' button on the output page that takes them back to input but then for some reason the user can no longer edit the value cell.

Comment: @JamesBaker Told you they were flaky.